# Discord.py on_message not working with intent enabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am creating a bot in discord and attempting to have my bot read messages to keep count of certain buzzwords used for fun. I have privileged intents ticked in the developer portal, and I believe I have them inserted properly in the code, but the bot is not responding to any messages, but will respond to commands. I did change the buzzword names since they were a little less than clean. I also removed the commands that worked to play music since it doesn't pertain to the problem, but did keep the formatting in case.

```
import asyncio
import os
import random
import discord
import yt_dlp
import time
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from dotenv import load_dotenv

funcount = 0
coolcount = 0
alrightcount = 0
load_dotenv()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
Bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#', intents=intents)

yt_dlp.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                       'restrictfilenames': True,
                       'noplaylist': True,
                       'nocheckcertificate': True,
                       'ignoreerrors': False,
                       'logtostderr': False,
                       'quiet': True,
                       'no_warnings': True,
                       'default_search': 'auto',
                       'source_address': '0.0.0.0'}

ffmpeg_options = {'options': '-vn'}

ytdl = yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)
        self.data = data
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = ""

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
        if 'entries' in data:
            data = ['entries'][0]
        filename = data['title'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return filename

@Bot.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    if "hello" in message.content:
        print(message.content)
        await message.send("Hello")
    else:
        print(message.content)
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@Bot.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    global funcount
    if message.auther == Bot.user:
        return
    if "fun" in message.content:
        funcount = funcount + 1
        if funcount == 1:
            await message.send("There is now 1 fun")
        elif funcount == 10:
            await message.send("There are now 10 funs")
        elif funcount == 50:
            await message.send("There are now 50 funs.")
        elif funcount == 69:
            await message.send("There are now 69 funs.")
        elif funcount == 100:
            await message.send("There are now 100 funs.")
        elif funcount == 420:
            await message.send("There are now 420 funs.")
        elif funcount == 777:
            await message.send("There are now 777 funs.")
        elif funcount == 1000:
            await message.send(
                "There are now 1000 funs.")
        else:
            str(funcount)
            await message.send("There are " + funcount + " funs.")
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@Bot.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    global coolcount
    if message.auther == Bot.user:
        return
    if "cool" in message.content:
        coolcount = coolcount + 1
        if coolcount == 1:
            await message.send("There is now 1 cool.")
        elif coolcount == 10:
            await message.send("There are now 10 cools.")
        elif coolcount == 50:
            await message.send("There are now 50 cools!")
        elif coolcount == 69:
            await message.send("There are now 69 cools.")
        elif coolcount == 100:
            await message.send("There are now 100 cools.")
        elif coolcount == 420:
            await message.send("There are now 420 cools.")
        elif coolcount == 777:
            await message.send("There are now 777 cools.")
        elif coolcount == 1000:
            await message.send("There are now 1000 cools.")
        else:
            str(coolcount)
            await message.send("There are " + coolcount + " cools.")
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@Bot.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    global alrightcount
    if message.auther == Bot.user:
        return
    if "alright" in message.content:
        alrightcount = alrightcount + 1
        if alrightcount == 1:
            await message.send("There is now 1 alright.")
        elif alrightcount == 10:
            await message.send("There are now 10 alrights.")
        elif alrightcount == 50:
            await message.send("There are now 50 alrights.")
        elif alrightcount == 69:
            await message.send("There are now 69 alrights.")
        elif alrightcount == 100:
            await message.send("There are now 100 alrights.")
        elif alrightcount == 420:
            await message.send("There are now 420 alrights.")
        elif alrightcount == 777:
            await message.send("There are now 777 alrights.")
        elif alrightcount == 1000:
            await message.send("There are now 1000 alrights.")
        else:
            str(alrightcount)
            await message.send("There are " + alrightcount + " alrights.")
    await bot.process_commands(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

If anyone can see what the issue is, please let me know.

I've tried to change my intents, and made test commands to try and catch what message.content is being sent over but to no avail. It appears that the bot isn't getting the info at all. Commands work fully as expected though.

Comment: This is crazy. Why are you using two variables `Bot` (`discord.Client`) and `bot` (`commands.Bot`)?
You just need to use `commands.Bot` to create your bot.

Comment: Because every guide I've seen on making a bot used discord. Client, and then when introducing commands used commands.Bot, without bringing up that the original discord.Client was supposed to be removed. Besides, you use discord.Client to declare intents, don't you?

Comment: Why would you need `discord.Client` to declare intents?